# jui\datepicker class not found

Tags: yii2

I would like to use datepicker in my form.
So for that I have used the jui with below step:

- Added this line

> `"yiisoft/yii2-jui": "~2.0.0"`

in composer.json at root in my folder.

- Added this line in my form file,

> `use yii\jui\DatePicker;`

- Added the tag in my form file,

`<?= $form->field($model,'country_created_date')->widget(DatePicker::className(), ['clientOptions' => ['defaultDate' => '2014-01-01']]) ?>`

And when I run the form I am getting this kind of error:

> "Class 'yii\jui\DatePicker' not found"

I have also tried to update the composer using the composer update.

Any body can help me please.

Comment: You need to update `composer.json` file. run following command `composer update` at root folder location.

Comment: @gamith I have already try this one also.

Comment: You can run this command `composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-jui` at your application root folder.

Comment: right now I have just try to use this comman but inn cmd promt when I run this command, it will open the composer.phar file..!!! not getting what to do with this.

Comment: you use windows os ? if yes so you run this `composer require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-jui`

Comment: I have try this one, and getting the error, installation failed in command promt

Comment: what's the error occur?

Comment: No matching package found and at last line "installation failed, reverting ./ composer.json to its original content"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89163/discussion-between-gamitg-and-nim).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that **fxp asset plugin** is installed:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
```

After installing it try `composer update`.